# Track status of multiple async requests when using Spring @Async

Tags: asynchronous, spring-boot, completable-future

I am using spring boot for developing services in my application.

I have a scenario where-in the request submitted to the back-end would take some time to complete.

To avoid waiting the client I want to return the response immediately with a message your request has been accepted. The request would be in progress in a background thread.

I see Spring provides the @Async annotation which can be used to create a separate processing thread from the main thread and using that I am able to offload the processing in a separate thread.

What I want to do is when I return the initial response as accepted I also want to provide the client with a tracking key/token which the client can later use to check the status of the request.

Since there can be multiple clients who would be accessing the service there should be a way of uniquely identifying each client's request from another.

I see there is no such feature in Spring Async or Future which can return a tracking id as such.

One possibility I see it to put the Future returned in HttpSession and later use that to check for the status by the client. But, I prefer not to use HttpSession and want my services to be stateless.

Is there any way/approach I can accomplish my requirement.

Thanks,

BS

Answer (score 1):

Generate the *key* **before** calling the `Async` method, and pass it to the method:

```
String key = generateUniqueKey();
callAsyncMethod(key);
return key;
```

The `Async` method will have to persist the status of the execution somewhere (let's call it dataStore). When the client asks for the status using the *key*, you look it up on the dataStore and return it.